# angular2 basic authorization on get request - 405

Tags: drupal, get, http-headers, angular, basic-authentication

I'm trying to get basic authorization to work for a Get request, but I'm getting 2 exceptions:

`OPTIONS http://localhost/drupal/user/1?_format=json`

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/drupal/user/1?_format=json. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405`

I'm using angular2 with drupal 8 backend

here is my service

```
var _baseUrl = "http://localhost/drupal";

@Injectable()
export class DrupalService {

  private actionUrl: string;

  constructor(private _http: Http, private _apiUrl: DrupalApi) {

     this.actionUrl = _baseUrl + _apiUrl;
  }

  authHeaders() {

     let username = 'username';
     let password = 'password';

     let token = btoa(username + ':' + password);

     var headers = new Headers();
     headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + token);

     headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
     headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

     return headers;
  }

  public GetSingle = (id: number): Observable<Response> => {
     return this._http.get(this.actionUrl + id + '?_format=json'
      , {headers: this.authHeaders()}).map(res => res.json());
  }

}
```

but it works when I try the same request from postman app

[image]

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postman, you are sending a header:

```
Authorization: Basic bXVyaGFmOmhleGFkZWNpbWFsMDU
```

But in angular you are passing:

```
  headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('bXVyaGFmOmhleGFkZWNpbWFsMDU'));
```

which will end up being:

```
Authorization: Basic YlhWeWFHRm1PbWhsZUdGa1pXTnBiV0ZzTURV
```

So, just don't convert the string to base64

```
headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic bXVyaGFmOmhleGFkZWNpbWFsMDU');
```

## Update

Error code 405 means : `Method Not Allowed`, Which means, drupal does not allow `OPTIONS` requests. I've not worked with Drupal before. But, there should be a way to allow `OPTIONS` requests.

Comment: you are right, I have updated my question and code. I'm getting 405 response

Comment: @MurhafSousli I have updated my answer. [check this out](https://www.drupal.org/node/2311695), it has some patches to allow `OPTIONS` method

Comment: @MurhafSousli how about [this way](http://enzolutions.com/articles/2014/09/08/how-to-enable-cors-requests-against-drupal-8/). It'll help to search for 'enabling CORS on drupal 8', because preflight request are only sent for [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) requests

Comment: yea I have already commented on the guy's article, his patch didn't working, it broke the site, I gave up on drupal